# Moving inline Youtube API javascript code to a seprate file

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, jsfiddle, youtube-javascript-api

I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4WPmY/6/).

When I move the script from the upper panel to the lower panel, it does not work any more. 
And why can't I use jQuery to target the buttons? Now, I have to use vanilla JavaScript, because jQuery does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSFiddle, at the left panel <sup>[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efivl.png)</sup>, you can choose where to place the script. By default, it's wrapped in an `onload` event within the head. By default, the Mootools library is loaded.

The reason that the YouTube Player API does not work with the default settings is that the API expects a **global** `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` event to be defined. When the code is wrapped in an `onload` event, the function isn't global any more.

The solution is to properly use JSFiddle: Use `no wrap (body)` and `jQuery 1.7.2`: http://jsfiddle.net/4WPmY/12/.

Another solution, though less nice than the recommended one, is to globally define `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` by setting it as a property of `window`: http://jsfiddle.net/4WPmY/13/

```
window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function () {
```

Comment: This works on jsfiddle, but actually taking the code and putting it in a js file and liking the file in the header does not work. Even when I copy your code where you globaly defined onYouTube...

Comment: @halliewuud Are you testing on a `file:` protocol? That won't work, because `postMessage` (the core method of the YouTube frame API) does not function on `file:`.

Comment: no I am doing a regular <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

Comment: @halliewuud But are you testing the page **locally**, e.g. at `file://C:\Users\User\test.htm`, `file:///home/user/test.htm`, etc? If yes, that's the problem, as explained in my previous comment. If not, copy-paste your source code, and put it in your question and/or http://pastebin.com/

Answer (score 0):

From the left pane of jsFiddle, in the section titled "Choose Framework" you need to change the first setting to `no wrap (body)` so the JS panel is run after the DOM is loaded. You should also change the second option to `jQuery 1.7.2` if you wish to use that library.

**Your fiddle, updated:** http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/4WPmY/11/