# Youtube iframe player doesn't embed using Youtube's Player API

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am referring to the [example code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Examples) provided by Youtube seen below. The sample code is suppose to ....

> The sample HTML page below creates an embedded player that will load a
>   video, play it for six seconds, and then stop the playback.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonkim/gDMQY/) for the code above.

Can you tell why this isn't working?

Comment: Change `onload` at the left side to `nowrap (head)`. This is caused by the the fact that `onYouTubePlayerReady` must be global. Fix 1: `window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = ...` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gDMQY/3/)). Alternative fix 2: `no wrap (head)` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gDMQY/4/))

Comment: Thanks Rob. That worked on jsFiddle. How do I do this on regular browser now, say on Chrome?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving inline Youtube API javascript code to a seprate file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284171/moving-inline-youtube-api-javascript-code-to-a-seprate-file)

Comment: View the source of the [generated page of JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonkim/gDMQY/show/): You'll see that JSFiddle wraps all supplied code in other tags. Copy-paste the documentation's example and save it in a `.html` file, and it will work flawlessly (provided that the file is hosted, because `postMessage` does not work well on the `file:` protocol (`postMessage` is used to transfer API requests).

Comment: I am trying to run the file locally. So I am using file: protocol. I guess that's the problem.

Comment: @RobW - helpful but not an *exact* duplicate.